# How should a new service decide whether to launch with a crypto-token economy or not?

Tags: tokens, ico

Outside of the obvious ICO bubble and the ability to raise tons of money, what is the core value proposition of establishing a crypto-token that users can use within your service?

For anyone launching a new service, how should one decide between crypto-token powered economy vs. not?

Comment: [Does this “cool project” truly need blockchain?](https://medium.com/@pavelkravchenko/investor-guide-does-this-cool-project-truly-need-blockchain-bdde70a26bfb)

Answer (score 1):

The questions a company should ask are centered around whether the benefits of using cryptocurrency technology in general would help with the service being offered, and if so, then the question is whether to to create a private/custom cryptocurrency (e.g. an altcoin forked off of Bitcoin), or use the Ethereum network as a foundation.

Some benefits cryptocurrency technology in general provides:

- Distributed architecture resilient to any one node going offline
- Decentralized architecture where no central entity needs to be trusted
- Verifiable public ledgers of all activity within the network

Some benefits using Ethereum (a smart contract) rather than creating a separate cryptocurrency:

- Network already exists; no need to guide people how to set up nodes and join the peer-to-peer network
- Mining infrastructure already in place, so no need to figure out how to launch without being susceptible to something like a 51% mining hashrate attack.
- Data storage available; no need to design database servers for storing application state
- Universal currency (Ether) available to all users, so smart contracts don't have to worry about "shopping cart" or "credit card processing" integrations nor security.

Comment: This is excellent, but couldn't one argue that there are business mode reasons to utilize a crypto-token economy (let's focus on Ethereum-based crypto-tokens for this example, since they're easy to launch). Beyond decentralization, isn't there value in utilizing a market-driven crypto-currency to power transactions within your application?